# Nagios host notifications not sending via email or logging

Tags: notifications, monitoring, host, nagios

I am re-doing our nagios infrastructure with puppet but I am currently stopped at a seemingly simple problem (most likely a config issue).

Using puppet, I spit out some basic nagios config files on disk. Nagios reloads fine and everything looks okay in the UI but, when I mark a host down, it does not send a notification.

nagios.log shows:

> [1470699491] EXTERNAL COMMAND:
>   PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT;divcont01;1;test notification
>
> [1470699491] PASSIVE HOST CHECK: divcont01;1;test notification
>
> [1470699491] HOST ALERT: divcont01;DOWN;HARD;1;test notification

In production (where I have changed nothing), I see in nagios.log (after marking a host down in ui):

> [1470678186] EXTERNAL COMMAND:
>   PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT;PALTL12;1;test ey
>
> [1470678187] PASSIVE HOST CHECK: PALTL12;1;test ey
>
> [1470678187] HOST ALERT: PALTL12;DOWN;HARD;1;test ey
>
> [1470678187] HOST NOTIFICATION:
>   pal_infra;PALTL12;DOWN;host-notify-by-pom;test ey
>
> [1470678187] HOST NOTIFICATION:
>   pal_infra;PALTL12;DOWN;host-notify-by-email;test ey
>
> [1470678192] HOST ALERT: PALTL12;UP;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%,
>   RTA = 0.81 ms
>
> [1470678192] HOST NOTIFICATION:
>   pal_infra;PALTL12;UP;host-notify-by-pom;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%,
>   RTA = 0.81 ms
>
> [1470678192] HOST NOTIFICATION:
>   pal_infra;PALTL12;UP;host-notify-by-email;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%,
>   RTA = 0.81 ms

As seen in the logs, there is a HOST NOTIFICATION logged and sent directly after the HOST ALERT in prod. I have been exhaustively comparing config files today and I cannot find a reason why the new config stops short of the notification.

I have verified that notifications are enabled at the top level. I have verified that email can be sent from this box (though, I am using the logs to verify functionality, not email). I have also tried multiple other google suggestions (and will continue my search too).

Relevant config details below. Please pardon the verbosity of my configuration and lackluster stack-overflow formatting. Thank you in advance.

hosts/divcont01.cfg:

> define host {
>
> ```
>   address              snip   
>   host_name  divcont01                    
>   use          generic-host-puppetized
> ```
>
> }

host-templates/generic-host-puppetized.cfg:

> define host {
>
> ```
>     check_command                  check-host-alive
>     check_interval                 1
>     contact_groups                 generic-contactgroup
>     checks_enabled                 1
>     event_handler_enabled          0
>     flap_detection_enabled         0
>     name                           generic-host-puppetized
>     hostgroups                     +generic-host-puppetized
>     max_check_attempts             4
>     notification_interval          4
>     notification_options           d,u,r
>     notification_period            24x7
>     notifications_enabled          1
>     process_perf_data              0
>     register                       0
>     retain_nonstatus_information   1
>     retain_status_information      1
> ```
>
> }

hostgroups/generic-host-puppetized.cfg:

> define hostgroup {
>
> ```
>     hostgroup_name                 generic-host-puppetized
> ```
>
> }

contactgroups/generic-contactgroup.cfg

> define contactgroup {
>
> ```
>     contactgroup_name              generic-contactgroup
>     members                        generic-puppetized-contact
> ```
>
> }

contacts/generic-puppetized-contact.cfg

> define contact {
>
> ```
>     use                            generic-contact
>     contact_name                   generic-puppetized-contact
>     email                          <my email>
> ```
>
> }

objects/templates.cfg (generic-contact config only)

> define contact{
>
> ```
>     use                             my email  
>     name                            generic-contact         ; The name of this contact template
>     service_notification_period     24x7                    ; service notifications can be sent anytime
>     host_notification_period        24x7                    ; host notifications can be sent anytime
>     host_notification_commands     generic-puppetized-contact-host-notify-by-email-low
>     service_notification_commands  notify-by-email,service-notify-by-pom
>     service_notification_options    u,c,r,f         ; send notifications for all service states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
>     host_notification_options       d,r,f           ; send notifications for all host states, flapping events, and scheduled downtime events
>
>     register                        0                       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL CONTACT, JUST A TEMPLATE!
> ```
>
> }

commands/generic-puppetized-contact-host-notify-by-email-low.cfg:

> define command {
>
> ```
>     command_line                   /etc/nagios/global/scripts/nagios-mailx.sh -t my email -s "** notification Host Alert: hostname is hoststate **" -m "***** Nagios ***** Notification Type: notification type Host: host State: hoststate Address: address Info: output Date/Time: date"
>     command_name                   generic-puppetized-contact-host-notify-by-email-low
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...I was building my system within another pre-existing system (dangerous, I know) and my contacts were actually pointing to a generic-contact that had its notifications disabled.

Whoops :)